# Installing Ubuntu with 3 Drives

Tags: partitioning

I'm installing Ubuntu 20.04 on my main PC. I have 3 drives, a 250GB SSD, a 1TB HDD, and a 2TB HDD. I don't know enough about Linux file systems to partition everything out, but I know I want my /boot directory on my SSD. Is there a way that I can select where that one directory will go and let it automatically divide up the rest? If not, what do you think is my best option here?

Comment: how does this relate to ubuntu? please [edit] your question accordingly

Comment: I assumed it'd be obvious I'm trying to install Ubuntu but I'll update it so it's more clear.

Comment: Does it work for you: https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation ?

Comment: You do not want /boot but if UEFI the ESP - efi system partition and / (root) on SSD. Then more space on SSD can be /home or data. And all partitions on HDD can be data. You can mount various ways, but only use ext4 format, not any with NTFS unless also booting with Windows as Linux does not have tools to defrag nor chkdsk NTFS.

Comment: It does! Thanks! My only question would be if I could have my home directory on multiple disks, or have a partition span multiple disks.

Comment: while there are tools that allow you to span a drive, such as LVM, if any drive fails you lose all data on all drives. If you really want to span drives, you must have very good backups to another system/server. I prefer to keep /home inside my / (root) on SSD and then have data partitions on HDD. With large drives now, I also like to at minimum have a smaller (25-30GB) full install for emergency boot or testing settings that I may not want to keep in main working install. Data is in data partitions so installs do not have to be large.

Answer (score 1):

Operating systems and software will frequently need to access multiple files simultaneously, with files located in different parts of the disk.  Mechanical spinning hard drives perform very poorly with these "random reads" and SSDs excel at random reads since they do not have to physically seek to data on the disk.

So it would be wise to install your operating system and frequently used software on the fastest drive. It will result in a significant improvement of overall performance compared to installing the OS and software to a mechanical spinning hard drive.

The performance gap narrows with static files like music, videos, pictures, and documents, as these are generally loaded on demand, one at a time, in a predictable order.  Often, the difference is imperceptible during normal operation, even though read/write speeds are generally faster on the SSD.  The exception would be when copying or writing a large number of files at one time.  But if you're not doing that often, put them wherever you like.

It's not wise to over partition especially if you are new to Ubuntu.  You can use the guided installation to "Erase disk and install Ubuntu". You don't need to create any extra partitions.  You do not need to manually create a boot partition. You do not need a swap partition. You do not need a separate home partition.  Some advanced/veteran Linux users like to create a separate home partition as a matter of convention and also because it can be easier to format your system partition without deleting your home folder.  But it is not quite as easy as it seems to reinstall a new system and just attach the former home partition. /home contains a lot of configs that might not play well with a new installation, especially if it's a different version, flavor, or distro.   Creating partitions solely for the purpose of organization is unwise, as folders serve the same purpose and do not place artificial limitations on your space.

If Ubuntu will be your only operating system, then install Ubuntu to the SSD.  It would be easier to just use the whole drive, and I suggest that you do. Ubuntu itself will not take up the whole space but you can store frequently used data in folders on this drive to keep things organized.

Comment: Understandable. I guess I was still looking at this from a windows perspective which just doesn't work anything like Linux. If I understand correctly, both of my hard disks would show up under /dev. Would I just treat them like I would a D: drive on windows?

Comment: Mounted volumes will have a mount point somewhere in the root file system, usually under `/dev` or `/media` -- but your file manager will show them as volumes or devices.  Knowing exactly where the drive or partition is mounted is needed when you need to specify an absolute path.  But if you are using Ubuntu Desktop or another DE, mounted volumes will show up in your file manager and file picker in a way similar to what you are used to. Letter drives are a Windows convention, so there will not be an arbitrary letter assigned.

Comment: You can "Try Ubuntu" in a live session prior to installation and this is probably the better way to answer a lot of general questions about how the OS is laid out.  This is also a good time to try a few different [flavours](https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours), since it's hard to change the DE on an installed system and you might like another DE better.  If you want something closer to Windows, I'd suggest Kubuntu (KDE) - In addition to having a more "conventional" desktop experience, it has a lot more features than GNOME and is highly customizable with included system settings.

Comment: "veteran Linux users" don't do partitioning "as a matter of convention". They have good reasons to do so. You don't want an inconsistent system due to a full disk, especially but not only on servers. By paritioning you can ensure that free space on the system and the root user home partition will not be messed by e.g. heavy log entries each millisecond or huge downloads. The `/root` folder on a full partition might cause an inoperability by the admin. Then you would need to fix the issue my mounting the FS offline in an external recovery system.

Comment: I always do have at least separate `/root`, `/var` and even `/var/log` partitions. This already saved me many beads of sweat on the forehead in cases of server issues.
For absolute beginners I would recommend to do a single partition install but leave enough free space on the disk for further partitions in the future. So you can change your partitioning schema at any time you want.

Comment: @Quas Yes, my point is that partitioning of the file system is really only worthwhile in specific use cases, as you have pointed out a few. These are not really relevant though for the typical "daily driver" Ubuntu Desktop. My comment about conventionality is specific to the separate `/home` partition. This is less common as it once was, mostly due to the explosion in diversity of software and how they use configs and the relative difficulty of using the same `/home` on different systems.  That used to be a lot easier.